# Can't connect wpa_supplicant to wifi. SSID is not found even though it is listed in scan results

Tags: scripting, wpa-supplicant

I'm using a script to add a network to my `wpa_supplicant.conf` and reload `wpa_supplicant` to connect a new network. Something like this:

```
cat << EOF >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
  ssid="$1"
  psk="$2"
}

EOF

wpa_cli reconfigure
```

Then I simply copy the ssid from `wpa_cli scan_results` and type the password to the script and I'm connected. Every now and then the command fails to connect. Even though it normally works I get `CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND` in `wpa_cli` suggesting there is a typo in SSID.

Long story short the case was an invisible character, which get's hidden in console output of `wpa_cli scan_results`, yet the character is there and thus the SSID don't match.

So what would be the best option for my script to get the right SSID no matter [what crazy characters it contains](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32799/how-to-put-special-characters-on-ssid)? The output might look like this:

```
network={
  ssid="Some Cool Network N@me "
  psk="evencoolerpassword"  # ^ this character is \x20
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could use the `iw` command to figure out such a case, as it escapes the unpritable characters like so:

```
# iw dev wlp3s0 scan | grep SSID
SSID: Some Cool Network N@me\x20
```

Then I `vim /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and add the invisible character by typing `<C-v>x20` at the right position.